# IP real a través de un NAT con PHP

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el IP real de la PC de los clientes que entran a mi servicio que esta en el 192.168.1.1?

Ellos entran a través de un NAT, desde el 192.168.1.254 y los IPs reales de ellos están en el 192.168.2.X. Cuando la web me muestra, sólo me sale el 192.168.1.254, no el real del rango 192.168.2.X.

¿Hay alguna forma que, mediante una función o algo, me muestre ese IP a través del NAT?

Comment: mm espera tu quieres optener la ip publica o privada?, la privada de tus cliente no se puede en PHP

Answer (score 2):

No se puede.

- `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` devuelve la IP desde donde se origina (en este caso es el NAT).
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` podría devolverte la IP del cliente si se utilizara un proxy (pero no se suele configurar con un NAT).
- Algunos NATs podrían enviar el IP dentro de la petición, y podrías probar imprimiendo todas las variables del servidor con `print_r($_SERVER);`, pero probablemente no encuentres lo que estás buscando.